# AuraEnabled Apex Method - Too Many DML Statements: 1

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components

I am calling this JS method from a button inside of a flow, which in turn calls the Apex method **deleteContentDocument**. Upon button click I get the **Too Many DML Statements:1** error.

What I have tried so far -

1. I tried running the Apex method through Execute Anonymous Window inside developer console, it runs fine.
2. Upon research I have read removing AuraEnabled would fix the issue, that didn't fix. Also removing AuraEnabled doesn't even call the Apex method because I see not system.debug statement called.

Javascript:

```
deleteContentDocument(event) {
    let contenttoRemove = event.target.dataset.name;
    deleteContentDocument({
        documentId: contenttoRemove
    }).then(result => {
        console.log(result);
    })
}
```

Apex Method

```
public with sharing class HelperController {
    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static void deleteContentDocument(String documentId) {
        System.debug(documentId);
        List<ContentDocument> file = [SELECT Id FROM ContentDocument WHERE Id = :documentId];
        delete file;
    }
}
```

Why do I get this error? How do I fix it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't do DML inside methods annotated `cacheable=true`. Simply remove this specification.

From the `Lightning Aura Components Developer Guide` on **[AuraEnabled Annotation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/controllers_server_apex_auraenabled_annotation.htm)**:

> #### Caching Method Results
>
> To improve runtime performance, set `@AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)` to cache the method results on the client. To set `cacheable=true`, a method must only get data. It can’t mutate data.

Crucially, **it can't mutate data** means that you cannot do *any* DML.

---

**Cannot Perform DML**

```
@AuraEnabled(cahceable=true)
public static void myMethod() { ... }
```

**Can Perform DML**

```
@AuraEnabled
public static void myMethod() { ... }
```